# Materials when exporting to UE4

Tags: materials, .fbx, unreal-engine

When I export my asset from Blender to Unreal Engine 4 through fbx all the values (metallic, roughness, etc.) disappear and it's just a solid base color. Do I need to export all the values and textures as maps individually?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: Thank you, what would be the long answer tho?

Comment: See the link above ^